# C# - Regular Expression for NO numbers allowed

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate first name and last name from all existing languages.
So I want to validate that there are numbers in a string.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you want to rely on "alphabetic" characters.  People can and do use non-alphabetic characters in their names.

Comment: Since when does containing no numbers == valid first/last name? *mind blown* Seriously, "all existing languages" -> red flag right there that unless you really look into it, you should just allow anything except the empty string and consider it valid. For example, Arabic chat alphabet uses numbers in names (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet)

Answer (score 6):

```
[\s\p{L}]
```

would be the correct character class for this. But of course names can contain many more characters than those (how about `Tim O'Reilly` or `William Henry Gates III.`?).

See also [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: ok, you got a point, how do i check string to make sure that it is not contains any numbers. Thanks

Comment: Names *can* contain numbers (see Falsehood 15 in the linked article). Don't try to validate names. You can only fail.

Answer (score 2):

Just do !Regex if your validation is in a if statement.

```
  if ( !Regex.Match ( stringToCheck, "^[0-9]+$" ).Success ) {
      // TODO.
  }
```

Comment: This regex matches strings that contain only digit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't even have to use regex:

```
string tmp = "foo";
var match = tmp.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()) != -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this one and it should do the trick:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = regex.Match(stringValue);
if (m.Success)
    //TODO
```